# I forgot phpmyadmin root password

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, passwords, bitnami

everyone. I can't remember my PHPMyAdmin root password in bitnami. I use Amazon Web Server.
I have searched in Google but I can't anything.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to *phpMyadmin* config files you may find the password in `config.inc.php` in Authentication section. This file is on root of *phpMyadmin* folder.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The credentials to use when accessing the database using phpMyAdmin are the same ones you need to use when accessing the database using the command line. phpMyAdmin does not have any configured credentials. In this case, if you didn't change the default password we configure when you boot the instance for the first time, you would need to use the password that was shown in the boot log file or after running this command

```
sudo cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

You can learn more about the default credentials here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/

Before trying to access the database using phpMyAdmin, please ensure all the services are running by typing this command in the command line

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
```